# Java: Socket inputstream not receiving new objects

Tags: java, sockets

getting started with Java Sockets here.

I've got a server and a client. The client sends a command to the server, "LIST_1" for example. The server will then generate a list of 3 Edge objects and send them to the client.
If the command is "List_2" it will generate a list of 12 Edge objects, "List_3" 48 and so on.

My problem is it works the first time. If I send "List_1" I get a list of 3 Edge objects returned. But if I then send the command "List_2", I still only get a list of 3 Edge objects instead of 12.

I've tried debugging it with some System.out.println's on either side. It seems the server does generate the right List with 12 Edge objects, but the Client keeps receiving the same (old) List of 3 objects.

Server side:

```
private List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

        boolean done = false;
        Object inObject = null;
        String welcome = "#Welcome message#";
        out.writeObject(welcome);
        System.out.println("Clientconnection has been made.");
        while (!done) {
            try {
                inObject = in.readObject();
                if (inObject instanceof String) {
                    String rawCommand = (String) inObject;   //[Command]_[Level] 
                    String[] splits = rawCommando.split("_");
                    String command = splits[0];
                    int level = Integer.parseInt(splits[1]);
                    kochfractal.setLevel(level);
                    System.out.println("Command received: " + command + ", level: " + level);
                    if (command.equals("EXIT")) {
                        done = true;
                    } else {
                        if (command.equals("LIST")) {
                        edges.clear();
                        kochfractal.generateEdges();
                        out.writeObject(edges);
                        out.flush();
                    }
                  }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("!Invalid command received!");
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Object type not known");
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Client side:

```
    public void sendCommandList(int level) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
     String command = "LIST_" + Integer.toString(level);
     out.writeObject(command);
     System.out.println("Command send: " + commando);
     out.flush();
     List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
     System.out.println("Reading List..");
     edges = (List<Edge>) in.readObject();
     System.out.println("List has been read. # of edges: " + edges.size());        
}
```

Comment: Need to see the code for the kochfractal object..., particularly setLevel and generateEdges(). Also, your code is not thread safe for multiple clients, what if different ones request different levels concurrently? edges and kochfractal should be per client...

Comment: It's kind of hard to show it in here, so here's a link to a Zip with both projects in it. (Comments are in dutch but I hope you get the idea) https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6yr9afiezyjn31/JavaSockets.rar?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, added out.reset(); after the flush on the Server side. I thought flushing would be sufficient.